# Magento 2: preference not working in admin panel

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, preference

I am trying to override ConfigurablePriceResolver but can't override

**app/code/vender/module/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">       
    <preference for="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\ConfigurablePriceResolver" type="Vender\Module\Pricing\Price\ConfigurablePriceResolver" />
</config>
```

**app\code\Vender\module\Pricing\Price\ConfigurablePriceResolver.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vender\Module\Pricing\Price;

class ConfigurablePriceResolver extends \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\ConfigurablePriceResolver
{   

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Pricing\SaleableInterface|\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @return float
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function ResolvePrice(\Magento\Framework\Pricing\SaleableInterface $product) {       
        $price = null;
        foreach ($this->configurable->getUsedProducts($product) as $subProduct) {
            $productPrice = $this->priceResolver->resolvePrice($subProduct);
            $price = $price ? min($price, $productPrice) : $productPrice;
        }
        /* if (!$price) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('Configurable product "%1" do not have sub-products', $product->getName())
            );
        } */
         return $price === null ? null : (float)$price;
    }
}
```

Comment: check your namespace and module name in di.xml

Comment: app/code/vender/modile/etc/di.xml this should be app/code/Vender/module/etc/di.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

**app/code/vender/module/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">           
    <virtualType name="ConfigurableFinalPriceResolver" type="Vender\Module\Pricing\Price\ConfigurablePriceResolver">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="priceResolver" xsi:type="object">Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\FinalPriceResolver</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

Answer (score 4):

ConfigurablePriceResolver is virtual type both used by `ConfigurableFinalPriceResolver` and `ConfigurableRegularPriceResolver`. Therefore, to override it, you have to override the virtual type, not the class itself.

```
<preference for="ConfigurableFinalPriceResolver" type="Vendor\Module\Pricing\Price\ConfigurablePriceResolver" />

<preference for="ConfigurableRegularPriceResolver" type="Vendor\Module\Pricing\Price\ConfigurablePriceResolver" />
```